lmer - how to report results and group differences?
I want to test the effect of my treatment drug on different populations. I have 3 groups, tested at 3 time points, and one dependent variable.
My data:
ID <- c("P1", "P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P3", "P3", "P3",
        "P4", "P4", "P4", "P5", "P5", "P5", "P6", "P6", "P6", 
        "P7", "P7", "P7", "P8", "P8", "P8", "P9", "P9", "P9")
Groups <- c("Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1",
            "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2",
            "Group3", "Group3", "Group3", "Group3", "Group3", "Group3", "Group3", "Group3", "Group3")
Time <- c(1, 4, 9, 1, 4, 9, 1, 4, 9,  1, 4, 9, 1, 4, 9, 1, 4, 9, 1, 4, 9, 1, 4, 9, 1, 4, 9)
Score <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 9, 9, 10, 10, 8, 9, 8, 10, 9, 1, 4, 9, 2, 5, 8, 1, 6, 10)

df <- data.frame(cbind(ID, Groups, Time, Score))
df$Time <- as.numeric(df$Time)
df$Score <- as.numeric(df$Score)

After plotting, I believe there is a difference in score between groups, and an effect of time.
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, aes (x = Time, y = Score, color = Groups)) + 
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = 'line', size = .5, alpha = .5) +
  stat_summary(func="sd", geom="errorbar", width = .5) +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.05, height = 0.05,  size=2, alpha=1)


I compare models, going from simple to complex:
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
m0 <- lmer(Score ~ 1 + (1 | ID), data = df, REML = FALSE)
m1 <- lmer(Score ~ 1 + (1 + Time | ID), data = df, REML = FALSE)
m2 <- lmer(Score ~ 1 + Groups + (1 + Time | ID), data = df, REML = FALSE)
m3 <- lmer(Score ~ 1 + Time + (1 + Time | ID), data = df, REML = FALSE)
m4 <- lmer(Score ~ 1 + Groups*Time + (1 + Time | ID), data = df, REML = FALSE)
m5 <- lmer(Score ~ 1 + Groups + (1 | ID), data = df, REML = FALSE)
m6 <- lmer(Score ~ 1 + Time + (1 | ID), data = df, REML = FALSE)
m7 <- lmer(Score ~ 1 + Groups*Time + (1 | ID), data = df, REML = FALSE)

anova(m0, m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7)
....
   npar     AIC     BIC  logLik deviance   Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
m0    3 143.624 147.512 -68.812  137.624                          
m6    4 138.686 143.869 -65.343  130.686  6.9384  1   0.008436 ** 
m1    5 135.426 141.905 -62.713  125.426  5.2597  1   0.021824 *  
m5    5 121.975 128.454 -55.987  111.975 13.4516  0               
m3    6 133.636 141.411 -60.818  121.636  0.0000  1   1.000000    
m2    7  97.898 106.969 -41.949   83.898 37.7381  1  8.091e-10 ***
m7    8  72.490  82.857 -28.245   56.490 27.4078  1  1.648e-07 ***
m4   10  76.391  89.349 -28.195   56.391  0.0996  2   0.951421    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

I settle on m7, and proceed to fit the model:
model <- lmer(Score ~ 1 + Groups*Time + (1 | ID), data = df)
summary (model)
.....
Fixed effects:
                   Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)        1.476190   0.450917 21.000000   3.274  0.00363 ** 
GroupsGroup2       7.428571   0.637692 21.000000  11.649 1.26e-10 ***
GroupsGroup3      -0.761905   0.637692 21.000000  -1.195  0.24549    
Time              -0.006803   0.078894 21.000000  -0.086  0.93210    
GroupsGroup2:Time  0.051020   0.111573 21.000000   0.457  0.65216    
GroupsGroup3:Time  0.948980   0.111573 21.000000   8.505 3.04e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
....

I see significant group differences at @ Time = 0, and an significant interaction effect. I also pull the ANOVA table for this model:
anova(model)
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
             Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F value    Pr(>F)    
Groups      122.848  61.424     2    21 100.699 1.732e-11 ***
Time         31.347  31.347     1    21  51.390 4.563e-07 ***
Groups:Time  55.844  27.922     2    21  45.775 2.209e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Where do I go from here? How do I perform pairwise comparisons to demonstrate that when Time = 1, there is no difference between Groups 1 and 3, but when Time = 8 Groups 2 and 3 and difference from Group 1?
I have tried the following:
library(emmeans)
emmeans(model, list(pairwise ~ Groups), adjust = "tukey")
....
$`pairwise differences of Groups`
 1               estimate    SE df t.ratio p.value
 Group1 - Group2    -7.67 0.368  6 -20.824  <.0001
 Group1 - Group3    -3.67 0.368  6  -9.959  0.0001
 Group2 - Group3     4.00 0.368  6  10.864  0.0001
....

But it does not work for all pairwise comparisons. Instead of treating each Time point independently, it averages them:
emmeans(model, list(pairwise ~ Groups*Time), adjust = "tukey")
....
 Groups Time emmean   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 Group1 4.67   1.44 0.26  6    0.807     2.08
 Group2 4.67   9.11 0.26  6    8.474     9.75
 Group3 4.67   5.11 0.26  6    4.474     5.75
....
$`pairwise differences of Groups, Time`
 1                                                         estimate    SE df t.ratio p.value
 Group1 Time4.66666666666667 - Group2 Time4.66666666666667    -7.67 0.368  6 -20.824  <.0001
 Group1 Time4.66666666666667 - Group3 Time4.66666666666667    -3.67 0.368  6  -9.959  0.0001
 Group2 Time4.66666666666667 - Group3 Time4.66666666666667     4.00 0.368  6  10.864  0.0001
...

How do I proceed?
Here are some related questions, but I was not able to find an answer: example, example, example, and this example.

Welcome to CV. Note that comparing this many models invalidates the $p$-values from the eventual comparisons between groups, unless you correct for the number of models considered. You had better argue for a certain random structure from the perspective of your field of science, and then only simplify if it turns out too complex to estimate (e.g., convergence problems, singularity).

This seems to be more of a programming question. You can specify the desired values of the (continuous) covariate:
emmeans(model, list(pairwise ~ Groups | Time), adjust = "tukey", 
        at = list(Time = c(1, 4, 9)))
# $`emmeans of Groups | Time`
# Time = 1:
#  Groups emmean    SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
#  Group1   1.47 0.389 18.6    0.654     2.29
#  Group2   8.95 0.389 18.6    8.133     9.76
#  Group3   1.66 0.389 18.6    0.841     2.47
# 
# Time = 4:
#  Groups emmean    SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
#  Group1   1.45 0.266  6.5    0.811     2.09
#  Group2   9.08 0.266  6.5    8.444     9.72
#  Group3   4.48 0.266  6.5    3.845     5.12
# 
# Time = 9:
#  Groups emmean    SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
#  Group1   1.41 0.430 20.3    0.520     2.31
#  Group2   9.30 0.430 20.3    8.407    10.20
#  Group3   9.19 0.430 20.3    8.298    10.09
# 
# Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
# Confidence level used: 0.95 
# 
# $`pairwise differences of Groups | Time`
# Time = 1:
#  2               estimate    SE   df t.ratio p.value
#  Group1 - Group2   -7.480 0.550 18.6 -13.590  <.0001
#  Group1 - Group3   -0.187 0.550 18.6  -0.340  0.9385
#  Group2 - Group3    7.293 0.550 18.6  13.250  <.0001
# 
# Time = 4:
#  2               estimate    SE   df t.ratio p.value
#  Group1 - Group2   -7.633 0.376  6.5 -20.321  <.0001
#  Group1 - Group3   -3.034 0.376  6.5  -8.078  0.0003
#  Group2 - Group3    4.599 0.376  6.5  12.243  <.0001
# 
# Time = 9:
#  2               estimate    SE   df t.ratio p.value
#  Group1 - Group2   -7.888 0.608 20.3 -12.980  <.0001
#  Group1 - Group3   -7.779 0.608 20.3 -12.800  <.0001
#  Group2 - Group3    0.109 0.608 20.3   0.179  0.9825
# 
# Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
# P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates 

Note that your example data produces a singular fit. The random effect is at the boundary (equals zero). I hope that isn't the case for your real data.

What does "Group | Time" mean? It is treating Time as a fixed factor, or a random factor/covariate? And what would it look like if I had three fixed factors in my lmer model and wanted to compare all possible interactions?

The formula defines Time as a grouping variable. I believe you can do V1 | V2 * V3 and add values for another variable to the “at” list.

I see. But how would I do a within-group comparison? For example, how would I demonstrate that the average values for Group 3 is different at Time 1 and Time 9?

Your question is only sensible if you consider Time a factor variable. But it is a continuous variable. You need to check if the Time slope is significant for Group 3. The emmeans packe has a function for that,
